# Drag and drop Ignite UI tree view

Tags: c#, jquery, infragistics, ignite-ui, igtree

I am using Ignite UI for tree view drag and drop.

Is there any way to keep the dragged item in the list?
Once the item is dropped to new location, it removes item from previous location.   How to keep the item at both locations?

```
$("#StructureList").igTree({
                    singleBranchExpand: true,
                    checkboxMode: 'triState',
                    dataSource:  data,
                    dataSourceType: 'json',
                    bindings: {
                        textKey: 'LineName',
                        valueKey: 'LineID',
                        imageUrlKey: 'ImageUrl',
                        childDataProperty: 'FacDetails',
                        bindings: {
                            textKey: 'FacName',
                            valueKey: 'FacID',
                            childDataProperty: 'strDetails',
                                        bindings: {
                                            textKey: 'strName',
                                            valueKey: 'strID'
                                        }
                        }
                    },
                    dragAndDrop: true,
                    dragAndDropSettings: {
                        allowDrop: true,
                        dragAndDropMode: "copy",
                        customDropValidation: function (element) {
                            // Validates the drop target
                            var valid = true,
                                droppableNode = $(this);
                                if (droppableNode.is('a') && droppableNode.closest('li[data-role=node]').attr('data-value') === 'File') {
                                valid = false;
                            }

                            return valid;
                        }
                    }

                });
```

Comment: Going to need a lot more detail than that to help. Do you have an example you can share? Where are you dragging it from and what are you dropping it into? What is the expected outcome?

Comment: @SalvadorVayshun Thank you for your reply. Please refer jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/igniteuisamples/jsfiddle-samples/tree/master/EN/HtmlSamples/tree-control/drag-and-drop-multiple-trees/ Here when you drag item to another tree ( from left to right or right to left) it removes items and place it on new location. I want to drag item move to new list and still keep that same item at original location.

Comment: @SalvadorVayshun something similar to jquery sortable helper 'clone'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Ignite UI `igTree` has three different modes for drag and drop - default, move, copy.

default - dropped node is moved if no modifier key is held and copied if <kbd>ctrl</kbd> is held.
move - dropped node is always moved, thus removed from the source.
copy - dropped node is always copied, thus preserved in the source.

Here's the [docs](http://www.igniteui.com/help/api/2016.2/ui.igtree#options:dragAndDropSettings.dragAndDropMode).

In order to have it always copy set the tree mode to `copy`.

```
$(".selector").igTree({
    dragAndDropSettings : {
        dragAndDropMode: "copy"
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. I tried every option but I was holding CTRL key.

Comment: I tried using 'copy' option. It still doesnt preserves in the source until CTRL is held. I have all files included. Clear cache but still no luck. it works in jsfiddle mentioned in the question.

Comment: I updated your fiddle. The drag and drop mode needs to be set on the target tree as well, since the check for whether the node should be deleted is performed on drop. I updated your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fat503ft/

Comment: @rach I actually opened an issue about this. https://github.com/IgniteUI/ignite-ui/issues/663 For now use drag and drop mode on both trees. When the issue is fixed, you will no longer need the workaround.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help

Comment: @rach What version of Ignite UI are you using? The issue that I logged in my previous comment is not resolved and would be available in 16.2 onwards.

Comment: in .js file.. it says Infragistics.Web.ClientUI data source localization resources 16.2.20162.1035 .. am not sure if this is version number

Comment: Yeah, that is 16.2. If you want the fix to get the fix sooner than the next service release, you can open a support ticket and you'll be given a link to the next build that contains the fix.

Comment: Ok will do. Thank you for your help.

Comment: I submitted issue for the same on gitHub